# Enable and disable button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, button

I looked many examples here of enabling and disabling a button in javascript with jquery and any of them worked for me.

Here my desperate situation.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="mytext" runat="server" onkeyup="enableButton(this, 3)"/>
<asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" Text="Search" disabled="disabled" />
```

and my javascript

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function enableButton(control, chars) {
                if (control.value.length >= chars) {
                    $('#myButton').removeAttr("disabled");
                } else {
                    $('#myButton').attr("disabled", true);
                }
            }
        </script>
```

> **EDIT**

Hey fellows, finally I got it!

I registered the call of my javascript function in LoadPage event in the codebehind

```
mytext.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "enableButton('" + mytext.ClientID + "',3,'" + mybutton.ClientID + "');"
```

Thank you all you guys for the time!

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. You only stated that the examples you have seen work, so what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: @A.S.Roma - he does not want the user to be able to search until they type in at least 3 characters first.

Comment: Hey @MaximusDecimus, that's because the ID of the button is not `myButton` ASP.NET server controls automatically decorate the ID differently. You'll need to do something like `$("<%=myButton.ClientID%>").removeAttr(...);` in your server-side code to output the appropriate client-side jQuery.

Comment: @emgee Yeah I know but I thought that with  $ character it would find it. So I did what you recommend but I have a parser conflict. I decided  to write this inside the function : var buttonName = "<%=MyButton.ClientID%>";  alert(buttonName); ... BLANK!!!

Answer (score 4):

Disabled is a property, not an attribute.

Use:

```
$('#myButton').prop("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: `$('#myButton').prop("disabled", true);` and `$('#myButton').prop("disabled", false);` will work as well, but sometimes `true` and `false` as parameters is confusing.

Comment: Alert the value of "control.value.length" and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


function SetButtonStatus(sender, target)
{

if ( sender.value.length >= 12 )
document.getElementById(target).disabled = false;

else

document.getElementById(target).disabled = true;
}



</script>
```

HTML:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtText" runat="server" onkeyup="SetButtonStatus(this, 'btnButton')"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="btnButton" runat="server" Text="Button" Enabled="false" />
```

Comment: The name of the control in runtime change of name!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've done before.

```
//On document load
$(function(){
      //Set button disabled
      $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");

      //Append a change event listener to you inputs
      $('input').change(function(){
            //Validate your form here, example:
            var validated = true;
            if($('#nome').val().length === 0) validated = false;

            //If form is validated enable form
            if(validated) $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");                              
      });

      //Trigger change function once to check if the form is validated on page load
      $('input:first').trigger('change');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
$('#<%= myButton.ClientID%>').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add jquery library in the head tag?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I copied your code and it worked fine for me. I didn't require any changes as stated by others

Comment: I guess you may not have used ClientIDMode=static

Answer (score 0):

finally I got it!

I registered the call of my javascript function in LoadPage event in the codebehind

```
mytext.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "enableButton('" + txtTRReference.ClientID + "',3,'" + btnGetTR.ClientID + "');"
```

Thank you all you guys for the time!

Answer (score 0):

```
    function enableButton(control, chars) {
        if (control.value.length >= chars) {
            $('#<%= myButton.ClientID%>').prop("disabled", false);
            $('#<%= myButton.ClientID%>').css("pointer-events", "auto");
           $('#<%= myButton.ClientID%>').css("opacity", "1");
        } else {
            $('#<%= myButton.ClientID%>').prop("disabled", true);
            $('#<%= myButton.ClientID%>').css("pointer-events", "none");
            $('#<%= myButton.ClientID%>').css("opacity", ".5");
        }
    }
```

`disabled` works only in IE, it doesn't work in chrome, so add the css pointer-events none which changes the mouse pointer and doesn't allow the link to be clicked.

Edit: Also use `myButton.ClientID` when you don't use `ClientID = static`

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I already did it! See my edit post! When I do like that way, I get a parser conflict.

Comment: So, is `disabled` working for you now that you have added the script on page load? You can use button ID either the way I have given or using the code you added in the edit. Where are you getting the parser error and which code is giving you parser error?

Comment: I mean if I assign the javascript function to the onkeyup or onkeypress attribute on my TextBox control in the load page I can use the  MyControl.ClientID perfectly. So, now it's ok. But if I embeed the <%= MyControl.ClientID %> inside the javascript function I got a parser error.

Comment: It should actually work fine in both the cases. I tested it. Anyhow since it's working fine for you then that's okay.