# Viewbag data not persisting from Controller to view?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I searched SO for quite some time, so I do apologize if this is a duplicate post.

I want to disable the save button on a jquery dialog if the user has insufficient permissions, as defined by the app. However, after I change my permissions in the database to be read-only (thus disable the save button), I am still able to save the changes.

I'm attempting to set a value in the ViewBag object in my controller and return a partial view. The code in the controller is:

```
Boolean blnReadOnlyPermissions = IdentityHelper.ReadOnly;
if (blnReadOnlyPermissions)
{
    ViewBag.ReadOnlyPermissions = '0';
}
else
{
    ViewBag.ReadOnlyPermissions = '1';
}
```

In the controller, I have tried double-quotes ("), integer values, and actual text ("True", 'True'), all to no avail to set the value for the ViewBag. The code executes successfully and I can see that the ViewBag is set at least in the controller.

The view code is:

```
function EditDialogFocus() {
    var ReadOnlyPermissions = '@ViewBag.ReadOnlyPermissions';
    if (ReadOnlyPermissions == '0') {
        $('#dialog-Edit').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('#dialog-Edit').attr('disabled', false);
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled', false);
    }
}
```

The jQuery dialog is:

```
$('#dialog-Edit').dialog({
    open: EditDialogFocus,
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 1000,
    resizable: false,
    title: 'Edit Customer',
    modal: true,
    position: ['center', 'middle'],
    buttons: [
        {
            id: "btnCancel",
            text: "Cancel",
            click: function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }, {
            id: "btnSave",
            text: "Save",
            click: function () { UnloadForm(); SaveCustomer(); }
        }
    ]
});
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you change `var ReadOnlyPermissions = '@ViewBag.ReadOnlyPermissions';` on `var ReadOnlyPermissions = '0';` will everything work as expected?
What `ReadOnlyPermissions` equals to after assignment?

Comment: @Dima - I tried that too with no success.  ReadOnlyPermissions equals 0 when I put in an alert box right after assigning it to the var

Comment: What do you mean saying 'with no success'? Does it mean your JS doesn't work with hard coded variable's value?

Comment: The button was not disabled when the user has read-only permissions.

Comment: ok write the disabling code in if part and enabling code in else part. see does that behaves normal?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments thus far.  While waiting for the experts here at SO, I continued to work on it and add the code in the controller (which was in the ActionResult method called x), it was also put in the ActionResult method called Index.  It appears that it may be a scope issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var ReadOnlyPermissions= @(ViewBag.ReadOnlyPermissions);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That suggestion didn't work and resulted in the error message 'value of property {jquery dialog function name} is null or undefined, not a function object.

Comment: I think the problem is in the disabling/enabling of the buttons, Have a look to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795309/enable-and-disable-button/17795394?noredirect=1#comment25961732_17795394

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I tried using: $('#btnSave').prop("disabled", "disabled"); and the object doesn't support property or method 'prop'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TempData["hello"] = "My value"`
TempData can be used across multiple controller actions.

Comment: Just a word of caution, TempData is only available for request +1, a refresh on the page will kill it (actually it gets killed on first access, so you can't access it twice either). TempData.Keep() might help. Also RedirectResult and RedirectToRouteResult always calls TempData.Keep() internally.

Comment: I had instances when ViewBag did not work, but TempData did the trick.  Not sure if the refresh will kill it, something I'll need to test.

Comment: Object lifecycle: ViewBag/ViewData: request, TempData: request + 1